# Python - Sphinx and ReadtheDoc - Not showing correct language

Tags: python, git, python-sphinx

I'm setting a translation for a project:
http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/

That is hosted on:
https://github.com/vcaldas/python-guide-pt_br

When I generate the page, I can see the translation. However, online:
https://readthedocs.org/projects/python-guide-pt-br/
It appears the English version.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

It is a "case-sensitive" issue.
The language is pt_BR.

Locally, the folder was correct but the Github version was "pt_br".

This breaks all. silly mistake.